# Como Asignar un id o un name a un tr, al hacer click sobre un boton

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <tr><td>DEPTO Y FECHA</td><td>No.</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>RUT</td>**<td><input type="button" onClick="asignarid();" value="Asignarle id a este tr"/></td>**</tr>

    <tr><td>DEPTO Y FECHA</td><td>No.</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>RUT</td>**<td><input type="button" onClick="asignarid();" value="Asignarle id a este tr"/></td>**</tr>
```

Hola necesito asignarle mediante javascripth un id a cualquiera de los dos "tr", presionando sobre el boton que esta en dicho "tr". Manteniendo el otro sin id, hasta presionar el boton interior

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día.

Primero que nada debemos asignar un id a la Tabla "`<table id="tabla">`" y con Javascript podemos determinar cuando al hacer click en dicha tabla que elemento padre pertenece y colocar cualquier atributo con su valor, que en tu caso es un Id al TR.

Aquí el código basado en tu pregunta:

```
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <table id="tabla">
            <tr><td>DEPTO Y FECHA</td><td>No.</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>RUT</td>**<td><input type="button" onClick="asignarid();" value="Asignarle id a este tr"/></td>**</tr>

            <tr><td>DEPTO Y FECHA</td><td>No.</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>RUT</td>**<td><input type="button" onClick="asignarid();" value="Asignarle id a este tr"/></td>**</tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        
        function asignarid(){
            const Tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
            Tabla.onclick = function(e){
                if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
                    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id = 'valor_del_id';
                }
            }
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
```